# Sumar decimales en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo que sumar la parte decimal de un numero en php (4.27 = 2+7). Este es mi script:

```
<?php
echo "<center><h2><u>Números aleatorios</u></h2>";
for ($i=0; $i<20 ; $i++) {
  $numero=rand(100,999);
  $numero=$numero%100;
  echo ",$numero,";
  $primerdigito=$numero%10;
  $segundodigito=$numero%100;
  $sumatotal=$primerdigito+$segundodigito;
  echo "|| $sumatotal ||";
}
?>
```

Como puedo obtener el segundo digito? Creo que es una operación básica. No puedo usar funciones ni nada complejo, ya que es un ejercicio.

Comment: Formatea tu código, tío, lo pones todo seguido. Te falta un ; en la línea que asignas $sumatotal. Esto no es un problema PHP, primero tienes que pensar una forma de hacerlo, algo completamente independiente del lenguaje, y aquí es donde estás atrancado. Échale imaginación. Cuando ya tengas tu idea de cómo hacerlo, empieza a pasarla a código, y después ya es depurar el código si te da problemas.

Comment: puedas pasar las indicaciones del ejercicio que te dieron, no logro entender que es una operaciones básica para tu Materia???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues, para empezar, debes saber como crear números decimales con 2 dígitos decimales siempre. Cosa que no estás haciendo en ningún lado.

```
$numero = mt_rand(1, 999) / 100; //Generamos números aleatorios
$numero = number_format($numero, 2, '.', ''); //Nos aseguramos de que siempre hayan 2 decimales
echo $numero; //Mostramos el numero
```

Ya el resto es hacer bien los cálculos.

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) { //Recorremos 20 veces
    $numero = mt_rand(1, 999) / 100; //Generamos números aleatorios
    $numero = number_format($numero, 2, '.', ''); //Nos aseguramos de que siempre hayan 2 decimales
    echo $numero . " NUMERO DECIMAL</br>"; //Mostramos el numero
    $segundodigito = substr(strrchr($numero, "."), 2); //Obtenemos el segundo digito primero
    $primerdigito = (substr(strrchr($numero, "."), 1) - $segundodigito) / 10; //Obtenemos el primero, y le restamos el segundo
    echo $primerdigito . " PrimerDigito</br>"; //Mostramos el primer digito
    echo $segundodigito . " SegundoDigito</br>"; //Mostramos el segundo digito
    $sumatotal = $primerdigito + $segundodigito; //Realizamos la sumatoria
    echo "|| SUMA $sumatotal ||</br></br>"; //Mostramos el total
}
```

Comment: No puedo usar ninguna función, solo rand, pero la marcaré como respuesta. Sabes como sacar el segundo digito con operaciones basicas?

Comment: Todas son funciones básicas amigo... Sino, como quieres obtener algún carácter? Además, te están enseñando con rand(), cuando la que deberían usar es mt_rand()

Answer (score 0):

El manual de php indica que puedes usar una función simple como

```php
$twoDecimals = number_format($number1, 2);
```

por cada numero, y realizas su sumatoria, deberá funcionar si entendí bien

Comment: Si, pero tengo que usar una operación básica, nada de funciones, estoy en un examen ahora mismo. Dice que es muy sencilla.

Comment: Estás usando rand(), es una funcion...

Comment: Si pero esa si está permitida, es parte del temario, se supone que el segundo digito es el resto de X.

Comment: O sea que por tus medios no puedes usar alguna otra función ??

Comment: Nada de funciones que no sea rand...